# Mongoose sometimes skips adding data to DB when using Update method inside of Promise function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm writing an API using Node.js Express framework, which makes requests to some other external APIs. I need to have logs of each request in database (I use MongoDB via mongoose).

The problem is that when I'm trying to push log to array of sub documents by mongoose Update method, sometimes it saves in database and sometimes not, in both cases without any error.
Here's some parts of executing code:

**// externalApiCtrl module**

```
const request = require('request');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
const PolicyLog = mongoose.model('PolicyLog');

const updatePolicyLog = (id, log) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PolicyLog.update({ "policyId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
      { $push: { logs: log } }
    ).then(() => {
      resolve();
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};

exports.createPolicy = (policy) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // prepare request body and do some other stuff here

    let options = {}; // request options (url, method, headers & body)
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error)
        reject(error);

      let policyLocalId = httpContext.get("policyLocalId");
      // here comes the trouble
      updatePolicyLog(policyLocalId, {
        method: "reqName",
        request: "reqBody",
        response: body
      }).then(() => {
        resolve();
      }).catch(err => {
        return reject(err)
      });
    });

  });
};
```

**// Main controller module**

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let externalApiCtrl = require('./controllers/external-api.controller.js');
  externalApiCtrl.createPolicy(req.policy)
    .then(result => {
      return res.json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  });
};
```

So when updatePolicyLog function is called, looks like sometimes it resolves before mongoose Update method (PolicyLog.update()) is resolved.
Is there any way of solving such issue?

Comment: On first look, I can not see anything bad, but to make your life easier: k mongoose already returns a promise on queries since the last couple of major versions, so you don't have to manually promisify the query, which can make your code easier to read and avoid coding errors. Also, there are many packages like request also directly returning promises!

Comment: Thanks for comment. I started writing code with elder version of mongoose which had no promises on queries, so then I refactored it inside updatePolicyLog method. Also I used node v6.x.x., which had no built in async/await features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the solution. 
The problem was not with mongoose, but with **express-http-context** module. Sometimes during multiple parallel requests to API, the context was lost and the value of policyLocalId variable was undefined, so mongoose did not update the logs.
It happened on Node **boron lts** (v.6.16.0), updating it to **carbon lts** (v8.15.0) fixed the problem.